# T-SQL different result on same query with float variable

Tags: sql, t-sql, floating-point

Why do I get different results from this two queries?

First query:

```
  DECLARE @b FLOAT;
  SET @b = 100

  SELECT @b / 3 + @b / 3 + @b / 3
```

Second query:

```
  DECLARE @flt FLOAT; 
  SET @flt = 100 / 3

  SELECT @flt + @flt + @flt
```

I read much about float type in SQL but didn't get what is difference in this two query

(result of first one is 100 and on second 99)

Comment: SQL Server does integer division, so 100/3 = 33.

Comment: Exactly as @GordonLinoff said

Comment: but it was set to float

Comment: yes, but the division is 100 (an integer) divided by 4 (another integer). SQL Server then assumes it's performing an integer division, and assigns the result of it to a float (but it already performed it as integer division)

Comment: @Lamak What is the difference between the first and second query though? Both do integer division

Comment: @StefanRendevski what do you mean?, the first one assigns the value 100 to a **float**, and then uses that float in the division….so no integer division at all

Comment: yes, you are right, I get it, thanks, you can answer it if someone has same question to see this answer

Comment: @Lamak Ah you're right, I overlooked the declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the calculation is made first, then it is rounded according to the highest type.
Ie.

**In the first case :**

First, we have performed calculations, i.e. `@ b / 3 (33.33333333333) + @ b / 3 (33.33333333333) + @ b / 3 (33.3333333333333)`

And now we round it, so we have `100`

**In the second case :**

At first we have performed calculations, i.e. `100/3 ((33.33333333333))` rounded up to the highest type, i.e. rounded to `33`

And now we have further calculations `@ flt + @ flt + @ flt (33 + 33 + 33)` so we have `99`

Comment: yes as @Lemak said in comments, integer division occurred first that's why